# Fluent NHibernate reference to composite key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, composite-key

Imagine four tables: **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**. 
Primary key of **A** table is **ID_A**. 
Primary key of **B** table is **ID_B**.
**C** table has a composite primary key (**ID_A,ID_B**).
**D** table references all three other tables and has three foreign keys on two **ID_A** and **ID_B** columns. References from **D** table to **B** and to **C** tables are optional.

```
A             B             C             D
-------       -------       -------       -------
ID_A          ID_B          (ID_A,ID_B)   
     <--------------------- ID_A
                  <-------- ID_B          
     <----------------------------------- ID_A
                  < - - - - - - - - - - - ID_B
                                 < - - - -(ID_A,ID_B)
```

I declared mappings for **D** table as:

```
mapping.References(e => e.A).Column("ID_A");
mapping.References(e => e.B).Column("ID_B");
mapping.References(e => e.C).Columns("ID_A", "ID_B");
```

**The problem**: On attempt to select rows from **D** table I got **ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined** because Nhibernate mentioned **ID_A** and **ID_B** columns two times in generated SQL query.

**Question**: How should I specify mappings for **D** table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such situation, I just map C in D, A and B being mapped in C, thus you can navigate from D to A or B through C.

In my experience, trying to shortcut in such a situation was not having any strong benefit, and was causing too much issues (not worth the trouble). (Maybe I have not even ever achieved an actually functional "shortcut".)

Comment: Frederic, good advice. Unfortunately it is not suitable in my situation since **D.ID_B** is null-able and references from **D** to **B** and **C** are optional. I updated a question.

Comment: Well, then I only have the classical advice left: avoid composite key as much as possible, use surrogate key instead. This way, you would have a C foreign key column nullable in D, and its A foreign key. B foreign key should no more be helpful in D.